# spring web ResponseEntity can't serialization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-redis

if use @Cacheable for return value 'ResponseEntity',I got serialization error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity]
```

demo：

```
@Controller
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "logs")
public class LogController {
  @Cacheable(key = "#id")
  @RequestMapping(value = LogConstants.LOGS_ID_PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ResponseEntity<Log> findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
   //....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Cache objects should be `Serializable` but `ResponseEntity` is not `Serializable`.

You could add cache on the different level, so it would be possible to make return type serializable or add some customer serializer/deserializer which would be able to save `ResponseEntity`

Comment: Didn't work for my. My solution was to create a component to be the middle man.

Comment: This is incorrect - the problem was not that the *key* wasn't serializable, it was that the method return type was not.

Comment: @Madbreaks indeed it was a wrong answer, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to Serialize your ResponseEntity like:

```
public CustomeResponseEntity extends ResponseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7156526077883281625L;

    public CustomResponseEntity(HttpStatus status) {
        super(status);
    }

    public CustomResponseEntity(Object body, HttpStatus status) {
        super(body, status);
    }

    public CustomResponseEntity(MultiValueMap headers, HttpStatus status) {
        super(headers, status);
    }

    public CustomResponseEntity(Object body, MultiValueMap headers, HttpStatus status) {
        super(body, headers, status);
    }
}
```

Then it will work.

```
return new CustomResponseEntity(resultDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Yes, ResponseEntity is serializable, but it is not Deserializable. The reason is that ResponseEntity doesn't have a no-args constructor. But for deserialization there should бе a valid no-args constructor.